# Too many values to unpack (expected 2) while splitting string

Tags: python, string

I am looking to split strings at "(", this is working fine if there is only one "(" character in the string. However, if there are more than one such character, it throws a value error `too many values to unpack`

```
data = 'The National Bank (US) (Bank)'
```

I've tried the below code:

```
name, inst = data.split("(")
```

Desired output:

```
name = 'The National Bank (US)'
inst = '(Bank)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `split` method is splitting the input on both `(` characters, giving you the result:

```
["The National Bank ", "US) ", "Bank)"]
```

You are then attempting to unpack this list of **three** values into **two** variables, `name` and `inst`. This is what the error *"Too many values to unpack"* means.

You can restrict the number of splits to be made using the second parameter to `split`, but this will give you the wrong result as well.

You actually want to split from the right of the string, on the first space character. You can do that with `rsplit`:

```
data = 'The National Bank (US) (Bank)'
name, inst = data.rsplit(' ', 1)
```

`name` and `inst` will now be set as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

this is expected behavior of this function. When you split string with n separators, you get n+1 strings in return
e.g.

```
l = '1,2,3,4'.split(',')
print(l)
print(type(l), len(l))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rsplit with the maxsplit parameter like this, although you have to append the leading ( to your inst string:

```
>>> name, inst = data.rsplit("(", maxsplit=1)
>>> name
'The National Bank (US) '
>>> inst
'Bank)'
```

You may be able to get a little cleaner results by doing the same thing but passing a blank space as the delimiter:

```
>>> name, inst = data.rsplit(" ", maxsplit=1)

>>> name
'The National Bank (US)'
>>> inst
'(Bank)'
```